# How to fix inconsistency in Jackrabbit JCR (BundleFsPersistenceManager)

Tags: jackrabbit

We are using *JackRabbit* in production. Unfortunately we have some inconsistencies in the repositories which make the data not unreadable:

`ERROR ResourceServiceImpl - RepositoryException to JCR javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: 1661b5c`

The spring bean configuration looks like this:

```
  <bean id="repository" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl" destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="config" />
  </bean>
  <bean id="config" class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.config.RepositoryConfig" factory-method="create">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="jcrXml"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="${instance.repository}" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="jcrXml" class="com.example.misc.InputStreamBeanFactory" factory-method="createStream">
    <constructor-arg value="/jackrabbit-repository.xml" />
  </bean>
  <bean name="jcrSession" factory-bean="repository" factory-method="login" scope="session" destroy-method="logout" />
```

The `workspaces.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Workspace name="default">
    <FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
        <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
    </FileSystem>
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.BundleFsPersistenceManager"/>
</Workspace>
```

From what I've learned (too late) [here](https://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ#Bundle_File-System_PM), the above configured *BundleFsPersistenceManager* can become inconsistent. It is also writen here that this should **NOT** be used into production. Well, it is now in production and no one has noticed this before and we would like to exchange this. However first we have to migrate the data and for this reason we need to fix it.

My question: **Is there a way to fix this or are these data lost for good?**

My second question: **What can we do to avoid these issues in the future?**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some notes about additional `check..` params that can be set on persistence managers on [Adobe CQ - Repository Inconsistency](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/RepositoryInconsistency.html) (uses Jackrabbit). The [Magnolia - JCR Troubles](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/JCR+Troubles+FAQs) has a script example for searching for and removing broken nodes. I've seen an approach that combined the logic from this script (written in java) and the checking params allow for a repository to be brought back up and running long enough to get the content out.

To avoid the issues in future - where you want a standalone setup that doesn't use a RDBMS - I'd suggest `org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager`.

```
    <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.DerbyPersistenceManager">
      <param name="url" value="jdbc:derby:${wsp.home}/db;create=true"/>
      <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
    </PersistenceManager>
```